# Rotating an object till it's in line with two other objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

From the image below, I would like to rotate a game object C around another object A (by an angle d to position p1) till C is on the same line joining object A and B's positions over a given period of time. Please note that the angle d and point p1 are not known. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function:

```
var point = A.transform.position;
var axis = new Vector3(0,0,1);
var angle = d;
B.transform.RotateAround(point, axis, angle);
```

Update:
if the angle d is unknown, please use below snippet:

```
public GameObject A, B, C;
public bool RotateDone = false;

void Update () {
    if (!RotateDone)
    {
        var v1 = B.transform.position - A.transform.position;
        var v2 = C.transform.position - A.transform.position;
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(v1, v2);

        if (angle < 1)
            RotateDone = true;
        else
            B.transform.RotateAround(A.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), -0.5f);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that angle d is not known. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a 4th object **"D"**.

1. Instantiate a 4th object **"D"**
2. Position this **"D"** object in **"A"** position
3. Make **"D"** object *.LookAt* to **"C"**
4. Make **"C"** child of **"D"**
5. Make **"D"** *.LookAt* to **"B"**
6. Make **"C"** be parentless again (or set its previous parent to it)
7. Destroy **"D"**
8. ***Succeed.***

Comment: This works, but a little vector math avoids the garbage collection.

Comment: well you can reuse the object "D" :p